# Will a passive DisplayPort to DVI adapter work on my Thinkpad?

Tags: dvi, thinkpad, displayport

The Lenovo Thinkpad I have at the office has a DisplayPort output.  Not DVI, HDMI, not mini-DisplayPort.  Nothing in the office has a DisplayPort input: the monitors take DVI, the big screen takes HDMI, and all the Mac guys have their little white dongles for mini-whatever-mac-people-use.

(Yes, there are other DisplayPort-to-DVI questions, but they seem centered on hooking up [3rd output from a single video card](https://superuser.com/questions/118957/converting-displayport-and-or-hdmi-to-dvi-d).  I'm just trying to get one digital video signal out of my laptop.)

Monoprice sells several DisplayPort-to-DVI cables and adapters that look mechanically correct, but they come with this scary-sounding warning:

> This is a passive adapter. While DisplayPort connectors are capable of passing a DVI signal, DisplayPort and DVI signals are basically different and not compatible with each other. This adapter does not actively convert a DisplayPort signal into a DVI signal. In order for this adapter to function properly, you must have a DisplayPort source device capable of producing and passing out a DVI signal through the DisplayPort jack.

How do I know if my Thinkpad is something that's "capable of producing and passing out a DVI signal through the DisplayPort jack"?

Answer (score 2):

On my T410s, I have a Displayport to HDMI adapter that works. When I bought it, the guy that sold it had a similar warning but the price was so low that I bought it anyway. For the DVI, check this article on the Lenovo forum, [display to dvi](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Options-Accessories-Knowledge/How-to-connect-Thinkpad-displayport-to-screen-with-DVI-input/ta-p/398897)