# Connect non-displayport GPU to displayport monitor

Tags: display, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport

I am trying to connect my GeForce 690 GTX to Asus Swift PG2780. I have tried http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/product_index.aspx?pid=357&lid=1 but the monitor has no signal. Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like they might be related, possibly even duplicates: [Convert WQHD from HDMI to DVI-D or Display Port](http://superuser.com/q/874241/53590) and [Converting DisplayPort and/or HDMI to DVI-D?](http://superuser.com/q/118957/53590) (please indicate if either of these provide an answer to your question)

Answer (score 2):

As per description, this adapter is only good for up to 1920x1200 (presumably at 60 Hz). It’s limited to Single-Link DVI (SL-DVI in the product name). Your monitor has 2560x1400 at up to 144 Hz.

And then, there’s also the direction. It converts DisplayPort to DVI. Not the other way.

Simply put: Won’t work with this adapter, ever.

Your GPU however, *does* support DisplayPort. As per [NVIDIA specifications](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-690/specifications), the reference design is equipped with a Mini-DisplayPort connector. Use that.

Comment: Ok, so for instance <http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/itemdetails/0B47091/460/67FB3393C9474D4EBB539D3DC944B8CE> ? Is the bandwidth high enough to handle the  144 Hz?

Comment: Your GPU can do DP 1.2 and that’s what the display expects, too. So unless the cable is crap, you’re good to go. Cheap cables are usually available at Amazon, by the way. Because MacBooks are also compatible with this cable type, there’s plenty available. Of course, you should verify your graphics card actually has that connector.